# How to differentiate a gradient in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to differentiate a gradient in PyTorch. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149699/differentiate-gradients) link but can't get it to work.

My code looks as follows:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import grad
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class net_x(nn.Module): 
        def __init__(self):
            super(net_x, self).__init__()
            self.fc1=nn.Linear(2, 20) 
            self.fc2=nn.Linear(20, 20)
            self.out=nn.Linear(20, 4) 

        def forward(self, x):
            x=self.fc1(x)
            x=self.fc2(x)
            x=self.out(x)
            return x

nx = net_x()
r = torch.tensor([1.0,2.0])
nx(r)
>>>tensor([-0.2356, -0.7315, -0.2100, -0.6741], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

But when I try to differentiate the function with respect to the first parameter

```
grad(nx, r[0])
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: 'net_x' object is not iterable
```

**Update**
Trying to extend this to tensors:
For some reason the gradient is the same for all inputs.

```
a = torch.rand((8,2), requires_grad=True)
s = []
s_t = []
for input_tensor in a:
    output_tensor = nx(input_tensor)
    s.append(output_tensor[0])
    s_t_value = grad(output_tensor[0], input_tensor)[0][0]
    s_t.append(s_t_value)
print(s_t)
```

But the output is:

```
[tensor(-0.1326), tensor(-0.1326), tensor(-0.1326), tensor(-0.1326), tensor(-0.1326), tensor(-0.1326), tensor(-0.1326), tensor(-0.1326)]
```

Comment: I feel like the problem is that you're inputting the model into the grad function. In the example you linked, he used a middle-man function to do get a gradient I think, because the output, which is the first parameter, needs to be a sequence of tensors, not a full sized model, right?

Comment: @Canbach You might be right. I can't figure out how to change it though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to change if you want to have the gradients with respect to `r` is to set the `requires_grad` flag to True for this tensor :

```
nx = net_x()
r = torch.tensor([1.0,2.0], requires_grad=True)
```

Then, as explained in [autograd documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html), `grad` computes the gradients of oputputs with respect to the inputs, so you need to save the output of the model :

```
y = nx(r)
```

Now you can compute the gradients with respect to `r`. But there is one last issue : `grad` only knows how to propagate gradients from a scalar tensor, which `y` is not. So you need to compute the gradients with respect to each coordinate :

```
for x in y:
    print(grad(x, r, retain_graph=True))
```

or equivalently:

```
for i in range(y.shape[0]):
    # prints the vector (dy_i/dr_0, dy_i/dr_1, ... dy_i/dr_n)
    print(grad(y[i], r, retain_graph=True))
```

You need to `retain_graph` because without this flag, the computational graph is cleared after the first gradient propagation. And there you have it, the derivative of each coordinate of `nx(r)` with respect to `r` !

To answer your question in the comments :

Not an error, it's normal. So you have a batched input of size (B, 2), with B = 8. You get a batched output of shape (B, 4). Now, for each vector of the batched output, for each coordinate of this vector, you can compute the derivative with respect to the batched input, which will yield a gradient of size (B,2), like that :

```
for b in y: # There a B vectors b of shape (4)
    for x in b: # There are 4 coordinates
        # This prints a tensor of shape (B, 2)
        print(grad(x, r, retain_graph=True))
```

Now remember the way batches work : all batches are computed together to harvest the power of GPU, but they are actually completely independant. So al `b` vectors are actually results of the network from different inputs. Which means, the gradient of the i-th vector `b` with respect to the j-th vector of the input must be 0 if i!=j. Does that make sense ? It's like computing `f(x,y) = (x^2, y^2)`. The derivative of `y^2` with respect to `x` is obviously 0 ! Well consider `x` and `y` to be two samples from one batch, and you have you explaination for why there are a lot of 0 in your results.

A last sample of code to make it even clearer :

```
inputs = [torch.randn(1, 2, requires_grad=True) for i in range(8)]
r = torch.cat(inputs) # shape : (8, 2)
y = nx(r) # shape : (8, 4)
for i in range(len(y)):
    print(f"Gradients of y[{i}] wrt r[{i}]") 
    for x in y[i]:
        # prints a tensor of size (2)
        print(grad(x, inputs[i], retain_graph=True))
```

On to why all the gradients are the same. This is because your neural network is completely linear. You have 3 `nn.Linear` layers, and no non-linear activation function (as a consequence, this is literally equivalent to a network with only one layer). One property of linear layers is that their gradient is constant : `d(alpha*x)/dx = alpha` (independant of `x`). Therefore the gradients will be identical along all dimensions. Just add non-linear activation layers like sigmoids and this behavior will not happen again.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for explaining it so well. So just to clarify, the first output `x` of this `y` operation is the gradient of the first parameter (i.e. `1.0`) that I'm looking for? Looks like it's `(tensor([-0.1564,  0.1480]),)`. So is `-0.1564` the value I'm looking for? I should have also been a bit more specific, I'm interested in the gradient of the first coordinate (i.e. `y[0]`) with respect to the first parameter of `r` (i.e `r[0]`) only

Comment: Yes (I added another code snipper to clarify), the first `print` you get is the gradient of `y[0]` with respect to `r`. It's a vector, and each coordinate is the derivative with respect to trhe corresponding coordinate of `r` (so `r[0]`, `r[1]` ....). So if you need the gradient of `y[0]` with respect to `r[0]`, you're looking for the first coordinate of the first printed vector

Comment: Also, is there a way to extend this to tensors? If I have `a = torch.ones((8,2), requires_grad=True)`, and `net_output = nx(a)`. I tried calling `grad(net_output[:,0], a[:,0], retain_graph=True)`, but getting the error `RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs`. I believe you talked about this part, but so far I couldn't fix it. Any tips?

Comment: Yes, this message means you are trying to call `grad` on a non-scalar tensor, here `net_output[:,0]`. That is why I was doing the `for` loop : you need to iterate over each coordinate of your tensor, you cannot compute the gradient of a vector with respect to a vector. I don't know the shape of `net_output[:,0]`, but I know it is not a scalar

Comment: Ah that makes sense! So since `a` is (8,2), `net_output` has a size of (8,4), since `net_x` outputs 4 values per input. By doing `net_output[:,0]` I was trying to get the first parameter (like you showed me before). Anyway, what you suggested sort of works: `for x in net_output:
    print(grad(x[0], a, retain_graph=True))`. This doesn't bring an error, but it seems like I'm getting the same tensor over an over again: it's full of zeros, except for 1 line that is going down every iteration. Really weird

Comment: Please see my update if you'd like. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: I think I have adressed everything here. The thread is getting too big, so if you have further questions, I think you should open another thread for them specifically :)

Comment: This makes so much more sense!!! Thank you so much for taking all this time to explain it!!! I sat on this all day today