# How to use PyTorch's autograd efficiently with tensors?

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66976313/how-to-differentiate-a-gradient-in-pytorch) I found how to use PyTorch's autograd to differentiate. And it worked:

```
#autograd
import torch
from torch.autograd import grad
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class net_x(nn.Module): 
        def __init__(self):
            super(net_x, self).__init__()
            self.fc1=nn.Linear(1, 20) 
            self.fc2=nn.Linear(20, 20)
            self.out=nn.Linear(20, 4) 

        def forward(self, x):
            x=torch.tanh(self.fc1(x))
            x=torch.tanh(self.fc2(x))
            x=self.out(x)
            return x

nx = net_x()
r = torch.tensor([1.0], requires_grad=True)
print('r', r)
y = nx(r)
print('y', y)
print('')
for i in range(y.shape[0]):
    # prints the vector (dy_i/dr_0, dy_i/dr_1, ... dy_i/dr_n)
    print(grad(y[i], r, retain_graph=True))

>>>
r tensor([1.], requires_grad=True)
y tensor([ 0.1698, -0.1871, -0.1313, -0.2747], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)

(tensor([-0.0124]),)
(tensor([-0.0952]),)
(tensor([-0.0433]),)
(tensor([-0.0099]),)
```

The problem that I currently have is that I have to differentiate a very large tensor and iterating through it like I'm currently doing (`for i in range(y.shape[0])`) is taking forever.
The reason I'm iterating is that from understanding, `grad` only knows how to propagate gradients from a scalar tensor, which `y` is not. So I need to compute the gradients with respect to each coordinate of `y`.
I know that TensorFlow is capable of differentiating tensors, from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients):

```
tf.gradients(
    ys, xs, grad_ys=None, name='gradients', gate_gradients=False,
    aggregation_method=None, stop_gradients=None,
    unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.NONE
)
"ys and xs are each a Tensor or a list of tensors. grad_ys is a list of Tensor, holding the gradients received by the ys. The list must be the same length as ys.

gradients() adds ops to the graph to output the derivatives of ys with respect to xs. It returns a list of Tensor of length len(xs) where each tensor is the sum(dy/dx) for y in ys and for x in xs."
```

And was hoping that there's a more efficient way to differentiate tensors in PyTorch.

For example:

```
a = range(100)
b = range(100)
c = range(100)
d = range(100)
my_tensor = torch.tensor([a,b,c,d])

t = range(100)

#derivative = grad(my_tensor, t) --> not working

#Instead what I'm currently doing:
for i in range(len(t)):
    a_grad = grad(a[i],t[i], retain_graph=True)
    b_grad = grad(b[i],t[i], retain_graph=True)
    #etc.
```

I was told that it might work if I could run autograd on the forward  pass rather than the backwards pass, but from [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/10223) it seems like it's not currently a feature PyTorch has.

**Update 1:**
@jodag mentioned that what I'm looking for might be just the diagonal of the Jacobian. I'm following the [link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/41530) he attached and trying out the faster method. Though, this doesn't seem to work and gives me an error:
`RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs`.
Code:

```
nx = net_x()
x = torch.rand(10, requires_grad=True)
x = torch.reshape(x, (10,1))
x = x.unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, 4, 1)
y = nx(x)
dx = torch.diagonal(torch.autograd.grad(torch.diagonal(y, 0, -2, -1), x), 0, -2, -1)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly perhaps [`torch.autograd.functional.jacobian`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.functional.jacobian) may be useful?

Comment: Maybe. It's been a while since I looked into Jacobians so I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for. I can tell you what's the  expected output and maybe that will help? I need to get the partial derivative of each element in `a` wrt each corresponding element in `t` (i.e. `a[0]` with `t[0]`). Since `t` is a vector of length 100, and the tensor `my_tensor` is of shape (4,100), I'm expecting an output tensor of shape (4,100). Where the rows correspond to each vector (a,b,c,d), and the columns correspond to the derivative of that vector wrt to the `t` element

Comment: ah that would just be the diagonal of the jacobian so it may be overkill to compute the whole thing.

Comment: There appears to be an [open feature request](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/41530) but it doesn't appear to have gotten much attention.

Comment: @jodag Please see my update

Comment: I'm not really sure what that extra code was expected to do, but for first snippet you posted, you are simply computing the gradient of network output (a tensor) w.r.t. the scalar input x, which is exactly the jacobian. You could get the same results using `dx = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(lambda x_: nx(x_), x)`. But this doesn't seem to be consistent with what you put in the second part and comment about computing the partial of a[i] w.r.t. t[i] (which would be the diagonal of a square jacobian).

Comment: Oh I thought that you said that I'm looking for the diagonal of the jacobian from your previous comment and the link the attached. Which is what the code I added is trying to do

Comment: What you said in the comment, and what your code is actually doing in the question are different. In your comment you said you wanted the partial of `a[i]` w.r.t. `t[i]` for all `i`. This would be the diagonal of the Jacobian of `a` w.r.t. `t`. However, in the code in your question you compute the gradient of `y[i]` w.r.t. **scalar** `r` for all `i`. In the latter case, this is exactly equivalent to computing the (full) Jacobian of `a` w.r.t. `r` (i.e. the matrix containing the partial of each element of `a` w.r.t. each element of `r`).

Comment: As for the code in that link, I can't speak to the intent of the author, only that they are requesting that such a functionality be added to pytorch. It's possible that the example code example they posted has bugs.

Comment: @jodag Really appreciate the help! I solved it using what you said : ) 
Just wrote the answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe I solved it using @ jodag advice -- to simply calculate the Jacobian and take the diagonal.
Consider the following network:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import grad
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class net_x(nn.Module): 
        def __init__(self):
            super(net_x, self).__init__()
            self.fc1=nn.Linear(1, 20) 
            self.fc2=nn.Linear(20, 20)
            self.out=nn.Linear(20, 4) #a,b,c,d

        def forward(self, x):
            x=torch.tanh(self.fc1(x))
            x=torch.tanh(self.fc2(x))
            x=self.out(x)
            return x

nx = net_x()

#input
t = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.2], requires_grad = True) #input vector
t = torch.reshape(t, (3,1)) #reshape for batch
```

My approach so far was to iterate through the input since `grad` wants a scalar value as mentioned above:

```
#method 1
for timestep in t:
    y = nx(timestep) 
    print(grad(y[0],timestep, retain_graph=True)) #0 for the first vector (i.e "a"), 1 for the 2nd vector (i.e "b")

>>>
(tensor([-0.0142]),)
(tensor([-0.0517]),)
(tensor([-0.0634]),)
```

Using the diagonal of the Jacobian seems more efficient and gives the same results:

```
#method 2
dx = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(lambda t_: nx(t_), t)
dx = torch.diagonal(torch.diagonal(dx, 0, -1), 0)[0] #first vector
#dx = torch.diagonal(torch.diagonal(dx, 1, -1), 0)[0] #2nd vector
#dx = torch.diagonal(torch.diagonal(dx, 2, -1), 0)[0] #3rd vector
#dx = torch.diagonal(torch.diagonal(dx, 3, -1), 0)[0] #4th vector
dx

>>>
tensor([-0.0142, -0.0517, -0.0634])
```